# How to make Exposé in Snow Leopard hide minimized windows?

Tags: macos, mac, expose

Exposé shows the minimized windows under a faint line on the bottom third of the screen.

How can I make Exposé HIDE those minimized windows, in Snow Leopard?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Exposé shows the minimized windows under a faint line on the bottom third of the screen. Can you give an example of where you're not seeing the minimized Windows?

Comment: But *hidden applications* (Cmd-H to hide *an application*, versus Cmd-M or the yellow control button in the title bar to minimize *a window*) are *not* shown. Maybe that is causing the confusion?

Comment: sorry, i meant HIDE and not SHOW

Comment: To me the question is pretty clear. When I press to hide (CMD + H) I want the minimized windows to be hidden all together with the whole app. That just doesn't happen by default. Oh well, now I noticed it was edited. At the bad side, this question is 1 year old and still unanswered!

Comment: We should probably all submit bug reports to Apple. Especially that hidden applications' minimized windows are shown drives me nuts. Unfortunately, I can already predict the outcome: "Engineering believes this issue has been addressed in Mac OS X Lion."

Comment: @DanielBeck seems you were right on spot! :P  this issue has been addressed in Lion... though it's still bad at managing minimized windows.

Answer (score 2):

The commenter (fideli) is correct, it is the default behavior to show them at the bottom of the screen.  If you want it to only show the minimized windows that is another question, but I am pretty sure that is not an option, and given the closed source nature of OS X's UI, not something that could be easily hacked.